# Css columns not looking right

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Hi I was wondering if there is a better what to do this because it is not looking right the way I have it set up.

Here is what I have so far, it looks terrible and I am using column-count but it doesnt look right here is an image of what it looks like right now.
[image: currently what it looks like]

This will change when the screen changes size and it will look ugly and it doesnt stay in 3 rows it makes a 4th for some reason... It is not supposed to go over the right side where the ads are and it is not supposed to cut it off at the bottom and have white space at the tops. I want to make this look like pinterest but I'm not sure how exactly to do this in jquery I just need these to line up and not cut off where it says views and pending. Please help thank you!

Here is my css:

```
#gallerycontainer {

   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    3;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         3;
   column-gap:           0px;
   column-fill: balance;
-moz-column-fill: balance;
-webkit-column-fill: balance;
   width: 840px;
    height:100%;

 position: relative;
}

#gallery li{
width: 265px;

}

#gallery li img {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
    max-width:250px;
    max-height:200px;
    padding:2px;

}
.galleryinfo{
     border: 2px solid #fff;
     padding-bottom: 40px;
     float: left;
     margin:9px;
     background: white;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;


}
```

And here is the html with php to get the images to show.

```
<div id="gallery">
        <div class="galleryinfo">
        <li id="<?php print $id?>">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="photos/<?php print $picture?>"><img src="photos/<?php print $picture?>"/></a>

        Views : <?php print($unique) ?>
        <?php print($pending) ?>
        </li>
    </div>
<?php
}}
?>
```

Thank you so much for all of you your help !

Comment: `<div class="galleryinfo">` shoud be `<ul class="galleryinfo">` and close with `</ul>` later in the script... or `<li>` another tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you want to have the Pinterest style. Check this out - it will help you:
http://demosthenes.info/blog/825/Pinterest-Style-Column-Layout-In-Pure-CSS

Answer (score 0):

set `<li>` or `<a>` with `display:inline-block` rule, it should not split over 2 column anymore .

If browser understand this rule : `column-break-inside: avoid;` , then it is the one to use to avoid a box to be sprayed into 2 col.

Comment: do you have a link to your gallery (if display+float are used , display has no effect)